# fixed gridview size with images asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView with an ImageField and a ButtonField in it.
The Image is large .. but i want it to be displayed in a smaller size in the grid.. so I'm looking for a way to fix the cell size of my GridView.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem; solved it this way:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="EliminarFuente" HeaderText="Eliminar" ImageUrl="~/Themes/Images/Delete.png" >                                                                    
    <ControlStyle CssClass="BotonDeImagen"/>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />                                                                    
</asp:ButtonField>
```

The CSS class is like this:

```
.BotonDeImagen
{   
    width:25px;
    height:25px;        
}
```

and the result is a centered image of 25*25 pixels.

**Alternative solution:**
You could define height and width on the ControlStyle tag, instead of using a CSS class.

Comment: This was only part of the solution for me. I also had to set "padding:0px"

Answer (score 1):

You can make set [`HighQualityBicubic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx) `InterpolationMode` when you do the BinaryWrite

Checkout [this example](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/102_GridView_with_Thumbnail_Images_%E2%80%93_Part_1.aspx) code.

Comment: I don't see any relation between this answer and the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these two properties on your `ImageField`.

```
ItemStyle-Width=""
ItemStyle-Height=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicity set the height and width of the image.  Use CSS to control the size of the rendered  tags.